# Keras stateful LSTM error

Tags: keras, lstm

I want to create stateful LSTM in keras. I gave it a command like this:

```
model.add(LSTM(300,input_dim=4,activation='tanh',stateful=True,batch_input_shape=(19,13,4),return_sequences=True))
```

where batch size=19. But on running it gives error

```
 Exception: In a stateful network, you should only pass inputs with a number of samples that can be divided by the batch size. Found: 8816 samples. Batch size: 32.
```

I did not specify batch size 32 anywhere in my script and 19 is divisible by 8816

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To dynamically size your data and batches:

Size data and training sample split:

```
data_size = int(len(supervised_values))
train_size_initial = int(data_size * train_split)
x_samples = supervised_values[-data_size:, :]
```

Size number of training samples to batch size:

```
if train_size_initial < batch_size_div:
    batch_size = 1
else:
    batch_size = int(train_size_initial / batch_size_div)
train_size = int(int(train_size_initial / batch_size) * batch_size)  # provide even division of training / batches
val_size = int(int((data_size - train_size) / batch_size) * batch_size)  # provide even division of val / batches
print('Data Size: {}  Train Size: {}   Batch Size: {}'.format(data_size, train_size, batch_size))
```

Split data into train and validation sets

```
train, val = x_samples[0:train_size, 0:-1], x_samples[train_size:train_size + val_size, 0:-1]
```

Answer (score 13):

[`model.fit()`](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit) does the batching (as opposed to [`model.train_on_batch`](https://keras.io/models/model/#train_on_batch) for example). Consequently it has a `batch_size` parameter which defaults to 32.

Change this to your input batch size and it should work as expected.

Example:

```
batch_size = 19

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(300,input_dim=4,activation='tanh',stateful=True,batch_input_shape=(19,13,4),return_sequences=True))

model.fit(x, y, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Comment: Then you should update your question with a minimal working example that replicated the error.

Comment: If you are using `validation_data`, the number of samples there must also be divisible by `batch_size`.

Answer (score 5):

there are two cases where batch_size error could occur.

1. model.fit(train_x, train_y, **batch_size= n_batch**, shuffle=True,verbose=2)
2. trainPredict = model.predict(train_x, **batch_size=n_batch**)
   or testPredict = model.predict(test_x,**batch_size=n_batch**)

in both cases, you have to mention no. of batches.

**note:** we need to predict train and test both, so best practice is divide the test and train in such a way that your batch size is multiple of both in **stateful=True** case

Answer (score 2):

Both training and validation data need to be divisible by the batch size. Make sure that any part of the model using batch size takes the same number (e.g. `batch_input_shape` in your LSTM layer, and `batch_size` in `model.fit()` and `model.predict()`. Down-sample training and validation data if need be to make this work.

e.g.

```
>>> batch_size = 100
>>> print(x_samples_train.shape)
>>> print(x_samples_validation.shape)
    (42028, 24, 14)
    (10451, 24, 14) 

# Down-sample so training and validation are both divisible by batch_size
>>> x_samples_train_ds = x_samples_train[-42000:]
>>> print(x_samples_train_ds.shape)
>>> y_samples_train_ds = y_samples_train[-42000:]
>>> print(y_samples_train_ds.shape)
    (42000, 24, 14)
    (42000,)
>>> x_samples_validation_ds = x_samples_validation[-10000:]
>>> print(x_samples_validation_ds.shape)
>>> y_samples_validation_ds = y_samples_validation[-10000:]
>>> print(y_samples_validation_ds.shape)
    (10000, 24, 14)
    (10000,)
```